# Android: Adjust a widget's parameters from outside the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, tabactivity, seekbar

My app starts with a TabActivity that has three activities associated to it, one for each tab.

I then have a singleton class that holds all the values that can be manipulated via these tabs, predominately using SeekBars.

However, some of the SeekBars need to be able to adjust values on other SeekBars, including those in another tab/activity.

I have listeners to detect the changes when the user adjusts a SeekBar. In this I update the value in the singleton. From there I want the singleton to be able to update the parameters on some of the other SeekBars.

Normally (non-Android), I'd get references to the UI classes to be able to access setter methods but I'm having difficulty in finding out how to do this as Android appears to do things a little differently (intents?).

Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we  switch from Tab B to C, Tab B activity is resumed (onResume called)

```
protected void onResume ()
```

if you change the value of a static variable in tab B and the switches to tab B.. the change will be refelected when u chk it in the Resume state

Override on Resume method.. put a log iniside the method and check

Answer (score 0):

Try (for this You need the `context object`):

```
public void sendBroadcast (Intent intent)
```

And on the `Activity` side use reciever method to receive the intent.

You can use `intent.setAction(string)` to provide additional information.